# Как в django правильно кастомизировать приложения?

Tags: python, django

Если я в virtualenv, устанавливаю и подключаю в свой проект, приложение, например "django-accounts" и мне надо переопределить свойства или методы представлений и использовать свои шаблоны, то как это сделать правильно?
Я сейчас создал новое приложение в папке с проектом и в нем наследую и переопределяю свойства и методы вьюх приложения которое установлено в virtualenv.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет единого правила или одного решения. Всё всецело зависит от самого приложения, которое вы собираетесь кастомизировать. Из своего опыта чаще всего приходится либо дополнять либо наследовать классы и super'ом перегружать методы родительского класса.

В пример могу привести приложение `django-oscar`

Изменить свойство класса

```
from oscar.apps.promotions.views import HomeView as CoreHomeView

class HomeView(CoreHomeView):
    template_name = 'promotions/new-homeview.html'
```

Или

```
from oscar.apps.promotions.views import HomeView as CoreHomeView

class HomeView(CoreHomeView):
    get_query_set(*args, **kwargs):
        # получаем queryset из не переопределенной версии метода
        # в том случае если этот метод возвращает его(queryset)
        query_set = super(HomeView, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs)
        # дополняем функционалом
        return query_set.filter(somefield=somevalue)
```

ссылки на документацию.

[- Как кастомизировать модели](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_customise_models.html)

[- Как кастомизировать вьюхи](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_customise_a_view.html)

[- Как кастомизировать Url](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/howto/how_to_change_a_url.html)

[- Оглавление](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/topics/customisation.html)